# pytorch PIP and CONDA error?

Tags: python, pip, deep-learning, conda, pytorch

Guys I am new to python and deeplearning world

I tried to install pytorch using conda

I get this Error...

```
(base) C:\WINDOWS\system32>conda install pytorch
```

> `Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

- pytorch

Current channels:

- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/win-64
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/noarch
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64

  Couldnt post all the channels due to reputation issue on stackoverflow...

Trying Pip for installing Pytorch It just opens pytorch site after this error:

> (base) C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install pytorch
>   Collecting pytorch
>     Using cached pytorch-0.1.2.tar.gz
>   Building wheels for collected packages: pytorch
>     Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pytorch ... error
>     Complete output from command C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-t86penrg\pytorch\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpqmo4j08upip-wheel- --python-tag cp36:
>     Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "", line 1, in 
>       File "C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-t86penrg\pytorch\setup.py", line 17, in 
>         raise Exception(message)
>     Exception: You should install pytorch from http://pytorch.org

---

Failed building wheel for pytorch
  Running setup.py clean for pytorch
Failed to build pytorch
Installing collected packages: pytorch
  Running setup.py install for pytorch ... error
    Complete output from command C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-t86penrg\pytorch\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-vms7q49e-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "", line 1, in 
      File "C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-t86penrg\pytorch\setup.py", line 13, in 
        raise Exception(message)
    Exception: You should install pytorch from http://pytorch.org

```
----------------------------------------
```

Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 878, in install
    spinner=spinner,
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\utils__init__.py", line 707, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
pip.exceptions.InstallationError: Command "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-t86penrg\pytorch\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-vms7q49e-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-t86penrg\pytorch\

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 385, in run
    requirement_set.cleanup_files()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 729, in cleanup_files
    req.remove_temporary_source()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 977, in remove_temporary_source
    rmtree(self.source_dir)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\retrying.py", line 49, in wrapped_f
    return Retrying(*dargs, **dkw).call(f, *args, **kw)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\retrying.py", line 212, in call
    raise attempt.get()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\retrying.py", line 247, in get
    six.reraise(self.value[0], self.value[1], self.value[2])
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\retrying.py", line 200, in call
    attempt = Attempt(fn(*args, **kwargs), attempt_number, False)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\utils__init__.py", line 102, in rmtree
    onerror=rmtree_errorhandler)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\shutil.py", line 494, in rmtree
    return _rmtree_unsafe(path, onerror)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\shutil.py", line 393, in _rmtree_unsafe
    onerror(os.rmdir, path, sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\utils__init__.py", line 114, in rmtree_errorhandler
    func(path)
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-t86penrg\pytorch'

I also tried conda install -c peterjc123 pytorch=0.1.12 and soumith but I get the same error not found

Any Idea where I am going wrong

Tried other forum tips and post also reinstalled Anaconda but still the same issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

However I found how to use Pytorch on windows here:
[https://www.superdatascience.com/pytorch/]

conda install -c peterjc123 pytorch

Did the trick for me ...

Comment: Tried lot of links before this. They didnt work. I can confirm that this one atleast starts the download.