# Could not import pytorch in windows

Tags: python, windows, pytorch

I am trying to install `torch` in windows to use with python. I have install `torch` and `lua` somehow.
Then I tried using:

```
conda install -c peterjc123 pytorch
```

from this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47960518/3584765).
It seems to have succeeded and asks for a new package to be installed:

> The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:
>
> ```
> pytorch: 0.3.1-py36_cuda80_cudnn6he774522_2 peterjc123
> ```

I don't have a GPU but thought it might use CPU (I am not sure about that but I proceeded anyway).

The problem is that after the installation I cannot import it:

```
import PyTorch
```

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytorch'

The code I tried was from [here](https://github.com/hughperkins/pytorch#create-torch-tensors). Does this seem normal? I would expect an error regarding functionality or something not about importing the module.

P.S. My initial intention is to run this [code](https://github.com/svishwa/crowdcount-cascaded-mtl) which uses `torch`. I am not sure how `torch` and `pytorch` are connected but I was hoping to make it work.

Comment: You have to use `import torch`.  In python this will import `pytorch`

Comment: Although the code at hughperkins use it differently I tried it and got `DLL load failed`. This means I haven't installed it properly?

Comment: If you use CPU only you could install `pytorch` in the Windows subsystem for Linux.

Comment: What do you mean by "pytorch in the Windows subsystem for Linux"?

Comment: You can run Linux executables natively on Windows as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10).

Comment: You should do 'import torch' as McLawrence pointed out.

Answer (score 3):

Use `import torch` to import the complete `pyTorch` library.